# How to remove purgeable spaze in Mojave

Tags: bootcamp, disk-space

I'm having some problem with my mac (MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)). I freed some spaces by deleting some folders but when I analyse mac HD I get the following:

```
Available: 79.29 GB (44.52 GB purgeable)
```

Installing windows 10 on bootcamp still returns the error "not enough space" so I started looking at tutorials on how to get rid of that "purgeable" space. I have tried everything, enabling store optimisation, apple cloud, disabling everything, nothing worked.

I stumble upon a tutorial that suggested to create fake files to fill the hard disk and then remove them (with iCloud disabled).

The problem is that the command suggested in the tutorial:

```
mkfile -n 10g ./test
```

Doens't work, it creates a file, but if I analyse the file:

```
Size: 10,737,418,240 bytes (4 KB on disk)
```

So it should occupy 10 gigs but in reality it occupies almost no space at all.

What can I do to get rid of that space?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tool like CleanMyMac, they usually have an option around the lines of "Remove System Junk".